# Верстка бутстрап

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите способ как разделить хедр как на скрине, желательно на бутстрап
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это делается простым градиентом без всяких **бутстрап** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pmghrs3/)

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .one {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #000 50%, #FFF 50%);
      min-height: 500px;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="one">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```